# Search string instantly by JTextField and JList

Tags: java, swing, trie

I'm making a dictionary application, which has a search function. When we type something to the textfield, we want receive a list result in the JList instantly, but I can't make it has been done instantly, always has latency, maybe 50ms.

Meanwhile I'm using another application, which can do it with 0ms latency. You can see it there: [video](https://streamable.com/m48zh5)

I'm using prefix tree. Here is my code:

Dictionary trie to search words.

```
// I have another arraylist **dictionary** contains all words
// you can see attribute **count** in DictionaryTrie, and **index** in Node
// You can see that: I use Trie to find index, and I use index to receive a list through dictionary
public class DictionaryTrie {
    private final Node root;
    private static int count;
    private static ArrayList<Word> dictionary;
    public DictionaryTrie() {
        count = 0;
        root = new Node(count);
        dictionary = Dictionary.getInstance().getDictionary();
    }
    
    public void insert(Word newWord) {
        String word = newWord.getWordTarget();
        Node currentNode = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            Node node = currentNode.children.get(c);
            if (node == null) {
                node = new Node(count);
                currentNode.children.put(c, node);
            }
            currentNode = node;
        }
        count++;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Word> search(String word) {
        ArrayList<Word> list = new ArrayList<Word>();
        Node currentNode = root;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            Node node = currentNode.children.get(c);
            if (node == null) {
                return null;
            }
            currentNode = node;
        }
        int start = currentNode.index;
        for (int i = start; i < Math.min(dictionary.size(), start + 15); i++) {
            list.add(dictionary.get(i));
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    
    private class Node {
        public Map<Character, Node> children;
        public int index; 
        
        public Node(int idx) {
            children = new HashMap<Character, Node>();
            index = idx;
        }
    }
}
```

Dictionary Management:

```
public class DictionaryManagement {
    
    private static DictionaryManagement instance;
    private static Dictionary dict;
    private static ArrayList<Word> listWord;
    private static DictionaryTrie dictionaryTrie;
    ConnectJDBC connectJDBC;
    Connection conn;

    private DictionaryManagement() {
        dict = Dictionary.getInstance();
        listWord = dict.getDictionary();
        dictionaryTrie = new DictionaryTrie();
    }

    public static DictionaryManagement getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DictionaryManagement();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    
    public ArrayList<Word> searchWord(String word) {
        return dictionaryTrie.search(word);
    }
}
```

Search controller

```
public class SearchController{
    private ListWord listWord;
    private JTextField searchField;
    private DictionaryManagement dictionaryManagement;
    
    public SearchController(ListWord list, JTextField field) {
        dictionaryManagement = DictionaryManagement.getInstance();
        this.listWord = list;
        this.searchField = field;
        this.searchField.addKeyListener(new SearchFieldListener());
    }
    
    private void search(String string) {
        ArrayList<Word> list = dictionaryManagement.searchWord(string);
        listWord.removeItem();
        if (list != null) {
            listWord.addItem(list);
        }
        listWord.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    }
    
    private class SearchFieldListener implements KeyListener{

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            String text = searchField.getText();
            search(text);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Main

```
searchController = new SearchController(listWord, searchField);
```

I think I have no problem with my algorithm.

Comment: Use a single column `JTable` which supports "filtering". Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for a complete working example.

Comment: @camickr thank you, but I really think that won't work efficiently with a huge database.

Comment: @dreamboy27 `JTable` was explicitly built to handle gigantic amounts of info. How big is your database that you think that `JTable` is not a good fit?

Comment: @davidalayachew I think this is Swing's render problem. Are you sure about "JTable was explicitly built to handle gigantic amounts of info"

Comment: @dreamboy27 I've used `JTable` to handle thousands of rows. Obviously, you will run into a memory limit at some point, but you were already approaching that limit if you are trying to hold thousands of rows of data in memory. If that is true, then you need to paginate the data. Let me know if that is where you are at.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the size of the table. I think the issue is that I would guess the filtering logic just does a linear search of all the rows in the table to determine which rows should be filtered.  I would guess the current data structure from above would do a more efficient search. Maybe multiple TableModels could be used to improve the search.

Comment: My algorithm is Prefix tree search. Of course the issue isn't algorithm. 
And I just show 15 items on list. So problem is swing's renderer @davidalayachew

Comment: @dreamboy27 If you are running into trouble with only 15 items, then the problem is definitely not the Swing renderer. Swing renderer starts to get slow on my (very weak and underpowered laptop) when I have around 10,000 elements. Up until that point, it is as smooth as butter and can definitely beat 50 ms. Please post your swing code. I believe the problem we are looking for is there. Looking at your algorithm, I can see that it is not slow. So I agree that your problem is not your algorithm, but I disagree that the problem is Swing. Let us see your Swing code and we will find out.

Comment: @dreamboy27 Oh, I guess I should have asked - how many elements are you working with? Is it more than 10,000? If so, then there are a few optimizations that could be made. Let me know.

Comment: @davidalayachew I updated my code. My dictionary has 140000 words, but I only show 15 elements.

Comment: @dreamboy27 Please also post the code for `ListWord`. But still, you said that your code right now is searching 140,000 words and only returning 15? That is definitely a lot harder for Swing to do in under 50 ms, but it is definitely possible. Let me know once you have posted the `ListWord` code. It is the morning before work for me, so I may take a long time to respond.

Comment: Also, if you could post a link to the 140,000 words, that would be appreciated. If not, I can make my own 140,000 words. But if you have yours handy, I would rather not go to the trouble.

Comment: @dreamboy27 I am back, but you still have not posted the code for `ListWord`. I need you to post that before I can write up a complete answer. Respond to me once you have done so, and I will write up an answer for you then.

Comment: @davidalayachew just a custom jList (custom listCellRenderer). But when I only use JList, the problem still be there. I will upload video as soon as possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @dreamboy27 Ok, post that code too please. I need to see it in order to provide a good answer.